# What happen or what happened

Tags: grammar

In making an inquiry which of the below should be used to properly format question.

"Which is correct and preferred: what happen or what happened?"

Comment: Bernadette, you might get more responses in future if you detail what you have done to answer your question yourself / research an answer already. I have answered below anyway, but as a rule you attract the assistance of more people if you follow these guidelines [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Have a great day!

Comment: They have different tempus, but "what happened" (imperfect)  is correct while "what happen" (presens) isn't. The reason "what happen" is incorrect is that the subject is 3rd person singular which requires an "s" on the verb. Correct presens form would be "what happens".

Answer (score 2):

"What happened?" is correct here.

If your question refers to the whole sentence

> "Which is correct and preferred: what happen or what happened?"

then I would rephrase it as

> Which is correct: "what happen" or "what happened"?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about the details of a past event, that should be

"what happened"

See [here](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-happen.html) (for details of how to conjugate the verb happen)

If instead you want to know about some future event you could use 'happen'.

e.g.

> What will happen tomorrow?
>
> What happened yesterday?